# how to apply the same rules to several selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a hamburger. This changes the color when hovering the container. Which one is the right way to write this in just one line of code:

`.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner{background:red;}
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner:before{background:red;}
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner:after{background:red;}`

I already tried many possibilities. I guess is a very simple answer but i don't know it.

```css
.hamburger-box{position:relative; display:inline-block; width:120px;height:24px}
.hamburger-inner{top:50%; display:block; margin-top:-2px}
.hamburger-inner,.hamburger-inner:after,.hamburger-inner:before{position:absolute; width:100%; height:3px;transition-timing-function:ease;transition-duration:.15s;transition-property:transform;border-radius:4px;background-color:lightgray}
.hamburger-inner:after,.hamburger-inner:before{display:block;content:""}
.hamburger-inner:before{top:-10px}
.hamburger-inner:after{bottom:-10px}
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner{background:red;}
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner:before{background:red;}
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner:after{background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-box">
          <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner::after {background:red;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to list your selectors, separated by comma `,`:

```
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner, 
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner:before, 
.hamburger-box:hover .hamburger-inner:after {
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: Correct, but pseudo elements are referenced using a double double-colon `::` so it's got to be `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: @connexo Thanks for correcting the typo. Yes, you should use `::` wen your write css3, but `:` is also Ok. I don't think that browsers will stop accepting the css2 syntax.

Comment: I thought there would be a simpler way. Anyway i didn't know about double-colon.